pynetbox - issue with creating devices from csv
I am trying to use pynetbox to create devices from a csv file. I have the following:
import os
import csv
import pynetbox

from pynetbox import api

def populate_device(dev):
    nb = pynetbox.api(
        url='<NetboxURL>',
        token='<Token>'
        )
                        
    nb.dcim.devices.create(
        name=dev,
        device_type=89,
        role=40,
        site=9,         
    )

os.chdir('<Directory>')    
with open('<File>.csv', 'r') as file:
    reader = csv.DictReader(file)
    for row in reader:
        dev=row["name"]
        populate_device(dev)

Which does not create a device or error out on me. if I change that create section to this:
result = nb.dcim.devices.create(  
        name=dev,  
        device_type=85,  
        role=35,  
        site=36,                     
    )  
    print(result)   

and run it, print(result) doesn't output the name.
I have also tried this, which also doesn't populate a device:
os.chdir('<Directory>')    
with open('<File>.csv', 'r') as file:
    reader = csv.DictReader(file)
    for row in reader:
        try:
            nb.dcim.devices.create(
                name=row["name"],
                device_type=89,
                role=40,
                site=9,
            )
        except pynetbox.RequestError as e:
            print(e.error)

If I run just this, then a device is created as expected:
nb.dcim.devices.create(
        name="TEST",
        device_type=89,
        role=40,
        site=9,         
    )

With that said, it shows that I have communication end-to-end, and that the account has proper permissions to create. Not sure where this is going awry, if it is a mapping issue or a wrong variable type? I am new to this, so I expect it is an amateurish mistake.


Is row["name"] returning anything? 2) I don't see that populate_device returns anything, so how are you getting 'hold' of the device?


@AdrianKlaver Yes, it returns the name(s) of the devices in the csv file. For example if I put print(dev) in my for loop, it returns the name. It seems like maybe an issue of getting it into the functions 'create' section. For instance, if I change that to this:
result = nb.dcim.devices.create(           name=dev,           device_type=85,           role=35,           site=36,                          )       print(result)    
and run it, print(result) doesn't output the name.

step through your code with a debugger, checking return values etc, show a sample of the csv file, also given a set of inputs so what you expect to see as a result of successful processing of those.
